# Why is my axios get request is not working (login)

Tags: html, vue.js, axios

I´m currently working on a login-page for a school-prohect. I´m using vue.js and tried to use axios to run my get-request. My problem is, that I don´t even get into .then() --> alert(TEST1) is the last thing showed.
I don´t get any error
Does anyone know why I have this problem and how to solve it?
Thanks!

CODE:

```
<template>
    ....
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6" id="formsCSS">
                <form id="login" method="get">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required maxlength="50">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                    </div>
                    <button @click="login" type="submit" name="login_button" class="block">Login</button>
                </form>
   ....
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    //import axios from './node_modules/axios/index.js';
    import axios from 'axios';
    export default {
        methods: {
            login() {
                var usrn = document.getElementById("username").value;
                var passwd = document.getElementById("password").value;
                var usesGranted = 50;
                alert("TEST0");

                this.doGetRequest(usrn, passwd, usesGranted, false);
            },
            doGetRequest(passwd, usrn, usesGranted, logedIn) {
                alert("TEST1");
                axios.get('https://moray.xyz/trawaapi/token/obtainToken.php', {
                    data: {
                        auth: {
                            username: usrn,
                            password: passwd
                        },
                        uses: usesGranted
                    }
                })
                    .then((response) => {
                        //Informationen die für Requests benötigt werden in der sessionStorage abspeichern
                        alert("TEST2");
                        console.log(response);
                        sessionStorage.setItem("token", response);
                        sessionStorage.setItem("password", passwd);
                        sessionStorage.setItem("username", usrn);
                        sessionStorage.setItem("uses", usesGranted)
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        //Neuen Token anfordern
                        if (error == 401) {
                            if (logedIn == true)
                                alert("....");
                        }
                        console.error(error);
                    });
            }

        }
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to prevent form from being sent. Change remove onclick from button and add another event to the form tag:

```
<form @submit.prevent="yourFunction" id="login">
```

As we prevent Email sending and just running `yourFunction` - we do not need to use `method` attribute.

Comment: Now I´m getting "Network Error" , "TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined" and 
"GET https://moray.xyz/trawaapi/token/obtainToken.php net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" any ideas?

Comment: It looks like something is wrong with this endpoint. It does not send a response